# Incorrect Syntax near Keyword 'Order'

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am getting and error Incorrect syntax near keyword 'Order'.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO Order (Cust_Num, Sale_Num) VALUES (@cust_num, @sale_num))", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_num", txtBxCustNum.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale_num", txtBxSaleNum.Text);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`Order` is a key word used in `Order by`

Correct like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO [Order] (Cust_Num, Sale_Num) VALUES (@cust_num, @sale_num))", conn);
```

Use [] to escape keywords that appear in table or column names.

Answer (score 2):

`Order` is a reserved word, and as such IMHO a bad name for a table. Nonetheless, you need to escape the name by wrapping it in square brackets:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO [Order] (Cust_Num, Sale_Num) VALUES (@cust_num, @sale_num))", conn);
```